# Execute function based upon select box result

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a normal select box as can be seen below, in a separate class i have a number of php functions. I would like to be able to execute functions based on the select box.

```
<form action="functions.php" method"post">
<select name="sales">
  <option value="week">Last 7 days</option>
  <option value="month">Last 30 Days</option>
  <option value="year">Last 365 Days</option>
  <option value="all">Complete report</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Then for example in my functions class i have functions `function week(), function month(), function year()`. I would like that when for example week is selected and submit is clicked that the week function would be executed, is there a simple method of doing this? Preferably on the same page but on a separate page would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what's wrong with a simple if/else statement?

```
if ( $_POST['select'] == 'year' ){ year(); }
else if ( $_POST['select'] == 'month' ){ month(); }
...
```

Comment: What if he wanted to add `day()`? or `decade()`?

Comment: yeah, that's what the `...` are for, why should a back-end developer need to go to html to figure out what functions might be being executed - that is crazy

Comment: No, what if after the finalized script is working, the client comes and say: "Yeah, it's good, but I want to filter by day as well! This means that in addition to writing the `day()` function, he would also need to search his code for this if-else statement, and add another clause in it. This goes against the concept of **abstraction**, which is designed exactly for these cases, because they are real, very possible, very likely cases.

Comment: You've tripped yourself here, if he didn't have the HTML code, how would he know he needs "year", "month", etc... He would need to look at the HTML code to know what functions to write...

Comment: no it doesn't you simple add another line of code `else if ( ... == 'day' )` ... it's the same, you'll have to go to your code and see where `call_user_func` is called but this way, back-end dev can see explicitly what functions are executed and has a complete control over it

Comment: @truth exactly, what if he doesn't have access to html code or even better of if the dropdown is dynamically generated ... how do you control the execution without explicitly giving allowed functions

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10495/discussion-between-truth-and-scibuff)

Answer (score 1):

add a name to your select `<select name="myvariable" method="POST">`

then you can use that name for calling function like:

```
echo $_POST['myvariable']();
```

or by using call_user_func() function like:

```
echo call_user_func($_POST['myvariable']);
```

(read more about call_user_func here - http://lt.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. Please write a full answer instead of jst providing a link to the manual.

Comment: I'm sorry but I believe that this is poor design. Why should a back-end developer need to go to html (which can be dynamic) to figure out what functions can be executed ... I would definitely prefer a simple `if/else if/else` here, or at least a hash table with inputs pointing to the functions

Comment: Yes, scibuff, you are right, you will never need to run the function like this because we cannot trust user, unless you are working with some administration interface which will never be tried to hack, so this implementation will be really good.

Comment: `call_user_func($_POST['myvariable']);` is a no-no - very unsafe, scibuff's solution is the way you should go

Comment: Im just answering the question, and my previous comment is telling when you can use such solution.

Answer (score 1):

On the most simple form:

```
$function = $_POST['select_name'];
$function();
```

Or (better yet),

```
call_user_func($_POST['select_name']);
```

---

#### Notes:

- You didn't add a name to your select, that is mandatory for it to pass onto PHP.
- You should probably validate the user input to make sure they aren't inputting something evil.

Comment: @scibuff: Which is why I said that he should validate his data. I'm not going to write his whole program you know, just provide a solution to his problem, and advise him to apply some coding security.

Comment: Wasn't expecting my program built for me, thanks for the suggestion.